# Standard back-button behaviour in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, back

The API says, I can overwrite the standard behaviour of the back button like this.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

But how can I grasp the standard  behaviour of the back button before overwriting it?
Something like:

```
standardbehaviour = document.getDefaultEventListener("backbutton");
```

or just the execution of the responsible method.

---

Is the standard behaviour the same as the one I get with `navigator.app.exitApp();` or are there differences?